# How to make syntactically correct names

Tags: r

How can I modify this so that it add `_` (underscore) in place of `.` (dot) as its default value.

```
> make.names(c("a and b", "a-and-b"), unique = TRUE)
[1] "a.and.b"   "a.and.b.1"

I am looking for the following result 
"a_and_b"   "a_and_b_1"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could enclose `make.names` with `gsub`:

```
gsub("\\.", "_", make.names(c("a and b", "a-and-b"), unique = TRUE))
# [1] "a_and_b"   "a_and_b_1"
```

Comment: This replaces existing "." with "_" and therefore can lead to unexpected results.